# Can I add out of the box renderings to custom component

Tags: sxa, best-practices

If I had specific html structure that I needed for a header for mobile responsiveness but inside it seemed appropriate to use the out of the box renderings such as image, linked list, search, link, navigation - how do I go about implementing this?

The header consists visually of an image next to two rows. One row could have a linked list next to a search box and then a login link. The next row could have a navigation bar for a drop down style menu.

Would I create a component with placeholders for the specific controls?

Or would I create a component that contained the specific components that I wanted to use - and if so how would I configure the datasources for these?

Or could I somehow clone a rendering (not sure what would be a good base for this) - and modify the html and add in the additional items that I need?

Comment: Have you tried all the OOTB components? Are you sure that you cannot achieve what you need with them? Or you asked a question to solve a problem that might appear in the future?

Comment: I can't achieve the markup that the UX wants me to use.  I can't wrap multiple components inside a div using a container without it inserting a row.  I can't set classes on that div without adding a site Style even though it's only to be used once.  I can't insert screen reader text inside an anchor tag.  As some examples.